# c++ boost split char

Tags: c++, boost, split

Given: `auto text = "-1|FUNCTION"s`

I must split it to a id: "-1" and a function: "FUNCTION".

My code:

```
std::vector<std::string> res;
boost::split(res, text, boost::is_any_of("|"));
log("ID: %d Function: %s", res[0], res[1]);
```

My result:

> ID: 12589 FUNCTION: …Ét"·

Comment: Your code is fine: See [here](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Z6JbApkcTuDNTHvJ). Maybe your text is not properly null terminated. As you don't show how you get it.

Comment: Please consider https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem in your code is that you are logging first `%d` and then `%s`, but in your argument list you have `res[0]` and `res[1]`, both of type `std::string`, both do not match your format list, so maybe your problem is with logging, change it to:

```
log("ID: %s Function: %s", res[0].c_str(), res[1].c_str());
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your problem is not from the split function.

The log function is expecting the address of a C-style string and you give it a string object. This is undefined behavior.

Try to log it like this :

```
  log("ID: %s Function: %s", res[0].c_str(), res[1].c_str());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem as others have said is that you're passing a `string` where `log` expects a `const char*`. Thought I'd post an answer to express that your solution would be much simpler if you just use the standard:

```
auto pos = text.find('|');

log("ID: %s Function: %s", data(text.substr(0U, pos)), data(text.substr(pos + 1, size(text) - pos - 1));
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/FQRTFw)